# Buscar ID de un dato laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-excel

**Hola** Estoy tratando de buscar el id de un dato, lo estaba tratando de hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$id = tbl_lab::select('lab_id')->where('lab_cliente','like','%'.$row['cliente'].'%')->first();
```

Pero esto me trae un dato así `{id=1}`

Tambien trate de hacerlo con `firstorCreate` de esta manera:

```
$id = tbl_lab::firstOrCreate([
        'lab_cliente' => $row['cliente']
    ]);
```

Pero me trae todos los datos de dicha tabla y me sale el siguiente error:

```
 Incorrect integer value: '{"lab_id":1,"lab_ceco":"ID0114","lab_cliente":"Lab Espectroscop\u00eda - ICP","lab_direccion":"Edif x","lab_lider":"Rafael M","l' for column
```

La forma como estoy importando es la siguiente:

```
return new tbl_instrumentos([
        'ins_usu_id' => $id,
    ]);
```

Como podria traer el id que necesito?

Comment: Cuál es el problema con el dato `{id=1}`? en qué se diferencia lo que buscas a eso?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que ese dato no me deja ingresarlo en mi base de datos, me sale lo siguiente  `Incorrect integer value: '{"lab_id":1}'`

Comment: Pero el resultado es correcto? es decir, comprobándolo con la base de datos, devuelve el id que toca?

Comment: Si, es correcto

Comment: Entonces el problema no es al buscar el id, sino al reinsertar los dato en la base de datos, por favor, comparte el código que utilizas para guardar en la bd

Comment: Listo, ya agregue el codigo

Answer (score 0):

No sé si entendí correctamente lo que necesitas. Podrías probar de la siguiente manera:

```
$id = tbl_lab::where('lab_cliente','like','%'.$row['cliente'].'%')->first()->lab_id;
```

Comment: Al hacerlo de esa manera me sale lo siguiente: `Trying to get property 'lab_id' of non-object`

Comment: Y de esta manera:
$id = tbl_lab::where('lab_cliente','like','%'.$row['cliente'].'%')->first()['lab_id'];

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la forma como tu lo tienes:

```
$id = tbl_lab::select('lab_id')->where('lab_cliente','like','%'.$row['cliente'].'%')->first();
```

Ya que el problema no es la consulta de en la tabla, sino que al momento de guardarlo en tu base de datos, intentas guardar en un campo de tipo `int` el resultado completo de la consulta anterior.

Puedes solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$onlyId = $id->id;
```

De esa manera guardas únicamente el valor del id en la variable`$onlyId`.
Luego en tu `insert` usas esa variable.

Comment: Lo hice como me dices pero me dice `'ins_usu_id' cannot be null`

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que al momento de registarlo en la base de datos lo tenia así:

```
return new tbl_instrumentos([
    'ins_usu_id' => $id,
]);
```

Lo que hice fue cambiar esa parte y dejarlo de la siguiente manera

```
return new tbl_instrumentos([
    'ins_usu_id' => $id->lab_id,
]);
```

Usando el metodo firstorCreate, adjunto codigo completo

```
 $id = tbl_lab::firstOrCreate([
        'lab_cliente' => $row['cliente']
    ]);


return new tbl_instrumentos([
    'ins_usu_id' => $id->lab_id,
]);
```